# Excel VBA prevents me from pasting values

Tags: vba, excel

I made a macro that computes the STDEV of a selection and puts it in the status bar, and so is called whenever the selection is changed. However, it has the unintended effect of preventing me from pasting values anywhere when I copy a range. I can copy, but then when I click somewhere else to paste the paste button becomes greyed out and I lose the selection. 
How do I get my paste back? Preferably by changing the macro but not by adding new ones.

Here is the code:

```
Public st As Double
Public rng as Range

Sub stdev()
On Error Resume Next
st = Application.WorksheetFunction.stdev(rng)
If Err.Number <> 0 then
    st = 0
End If
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = "Stdev: " & st
End Sub
```

Then:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target as Range)
Set rng = Target
Call stdev
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you change

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target as Range)
Set rng = Target
Call stdev
End Sub
```

to

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChagne(ByVal Target as Range)
If Application.CutCopyMode = 1 Then Exit Sub
Set rng = Target
Call stdev
End Sub
```

That should bypass your subroutine while you're copying and pasting something, without having to add a lot more code.

Comment: Amazing. This worked. Thank you so much! FYI you need to add End If

Comment: @farazmasroor The if statement is a single line, so it should process without an End If, or at least it is when I'm testing it.  Glad to know it works otherwise though.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `Application.DisplayStatusBar` is what clears the office clipboard. You could remove that line entirely or use

```
Sub stdev()
On Error Resume Next
st = Application.WorksheetFunction.stdev(rng)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    st = 0
End If
If Not Application.DisplayStatusBar Then Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = "Stdev: " & st
End Sub
```

That way it would only clear the clipboard if the status bar wasn't displayed.